# Actionbar and ListActivity in one Activity

Tags: android-activity, android-actionbar, listactivity

I have a program which shows lists of files in directories on the SDCARD and when the user clicks on a file it opens the PDF up.  For instance one activity will display the contents of one folder.

I have been wanting to add the ActionBar for navigation and can get the ActionBar to work in its own activity and my ListActivity to work in its own activity, however I cannot get them to work together.

I am not sure how to combine the two so that I end up with one activity that displays the action bar and the file list in the one Activity?

The Actionbar Activity starts with

```
public class SecondActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
```

The Activity that displays the clickable list starts with

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
```

My android app programming is quite basic and self taught so I am probably missing something obvious.  Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your target SDK version?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can extend your class to `ListActivity` and override method `onCreateOptionsMenu` to bind your action bar to the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_action_bar_name_here, menu);

        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }

    // your other methods
}
```

Comment: I Have managed to get it to work.  Thanks Hoang for your help.  I ended up doing the following "public class OperatingInstructions extends ListActivity  implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {"   I then included the methods for both within the one Activity.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I have posted an alternative solution that [separates the concerns of the List and the ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22493553/1798991). Makes the code a little tidier IMO.