# How to use getSupportActionBar() with activity extending ListActivity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

This is my activity where I want to use actionbar. My activity is extending ListActivity and I am not able to figure out: how to call getSupportActionBar() in this activity.

I checked out all the solution provided by users on stackoverflow. Please guide.

```
public class FileChooserActivity1 extends ListActivity {

    private File currentFolder;
    private FileArrayAdapter fileArrayListAdapter;
    private FileFilter fileFilter;
    private File fileSelected;
    private ArrayList<String> extensions;
    final int FILE_CHOOSER = 1;
    final int JPG=111;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // currentFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        currentFolder=new File("/storage/emulated/0/SALESKIT");
        fill(currentFolder);
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if ((!currentFolder.getName().equals("/storage/emulated/0/SALESKIT"/*Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName()*/))
                    && (currentFolder.getParentFile() != null)&&(!currentFolder.getParentFile().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("0"))) {
                currentFolder = currentFolder.getParentFile();
                fill(currentFolder);
            } else {
                Log.i("FILE CHOOSER", "canceled");
                /*setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                finish();*/
                Intent intent=new Intent(FileChooserActivity1.this,SplashScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


            }



        fileArrayListAdapter = new FileArrayAdapter(FileChooserActivity1.this, R.layout.file_row, dirs,currentFolder.listFiles());
        this.setListAdapter(fileArrayListAdapter);
        currentFolder.listFiles();
    }



   }
```

Comment: don't use `ListActivity`

Comment: I want LIstview so how can i get Listview without listactivity?

Comment: extending `AppCompatActivity` ? please bother briefly yourself with the reading of the documentation of  ListActivity

Comment: I want dynamic list.

Comment: ListActivity is just a simple activity where it has to have ListView with special ID. Use regular Activity, and add a ListView in it instead

Comment: is Action bar support in my activity  define my list in ListView?

Comment: Yes, it's supported. Use `AppCompatActivity` as others have suggested already. You need to keep up with the changes in the sdk :)

Comment: Thank you all let me try this approach .

Comment: Since you have done your activity as List Activity.Then in the AndroidManifest.xml file you can provide the theme for your List Activity. 
Please let me know if this is useful or not.

Comment: I did this already but doesn't work @SagarGangawane

Answer (score 0):

With **ListActivity** you do not get `getSupportActionBar()` method because `getSupportActionBar()` Method is for **AppCompatActivity** or **FragmentActivity**.

But You want to display `ActionBar with ListActivity` below link will help you.

[Actionbar and ListActivity in one Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875090/actionbar-and-listactivity-in-one-activity)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to use **ListActivity** instead to work with **actionbar(toolbar)**, now you can use **AppCompatActivity** that support the toolbar related modifications. If you wanted to have list in the activity then you can either use **ListView** or **RecyclerView** within your **AppCompatActivity**.